# Branch File Server Caching- Linux

Tags: linux, windows, cache, aws, replication

We want to centralize our Linux file server in the cloud (AWS). We don't want a full copy of each file to be downloaded every time there is a change to that file. I am somewhat familiar with Windows Branch Cache & DFS replication. HOWEVER we are using Linux File Servers for the physical office. Does Linux have any options like Windows Branch Cache? Any WAN Optimization would actually work?

http://linux.online4biz.net/2016/01/branchcache-guide/ (About Win Branch Cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has something called CacheFS, which can be used with NFS (or AFS).  This can be used to cache files on the local disk so that multiple reads are served locally and don't require hitting the network for the full file transfer.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CacheFS) goes into some detail of the underlying concepts.

There's a [walkthrough](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-redhat-install-configure-cachefilesd-for-nfs/) for CentOS/RedHat.

Comment: From what I have read NFS does not match up Samba cifs.. So cachfs even make a difference ?

Comment: You said you're using Linux file servers; why would you want to use Samba?

Comment: Ignore my comment above